# Jquery Select Boxes into Likert Table

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

So I am trying to use jquery to dynamically change an entire fieldset of selectboxes into a likert table of radio buttons.

I've found other solutions show you how to create a single select box into radio buttons but i kept running into walls when i was trying to create a whole table.

Answer (score 0):

I got something working but its kind of a mess and curious if others have a better way.

http://cdpn.io/EsIef